# Wrong Result With Sum Function When Use Inner Join In SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, inner-join, sql-server-2019

i have two Tables;

```
Human
-----------
id
Name
list<car> cars
```

```
Car
-----------
id
name
price
Human
```

I want the total price of a human cars,so i used this SQL code for this:

```
SELECT
SUM(Price)
FROM Cars
INNER JOIN Humans ON Cars.Human_id = 1
```

but result is wrong.

**for example:**

| id | name | Price | Human_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | car1 | 10000 | 1 |
| 2 | car2 | 15000 | 1 |

When I use that code for this table, the result is 50,000! But the answer must be 25,000.
It seems that this mistake has something to do with the number of registered cars.
can you explain why this wrong happen with sum function and inner join and calculate numbers multiple?

Comment: What do you mean by you have 2 classes? Classes don't exist in SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
SUM(Price)
FROM Cars
INNER JOIN Humans ON Cars.Human_id = 1
```

This a cartesian product between all Humans and Human 1's cars.

You probably want

```
SELECT
SUM(Price)
FROM Cars
INNER JOIN Humans 
 ON Cars.Human_id = Human.Id 
WHERE Human.Id = 1
```

Comment: Thank you For your Answe.Can you explain more about this event or introduce a reference for further reading, please?

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT SUM(Price) FROM Cars WHERE Cars.Human_id = 1`

Comment: thank you for your answer,your code work well,but i think that answer i accepted is more complete.